# how to loop through list and create separate dataframes in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, census

I am trying to pull in Census Bureau data on migration for the entire US by county.  Because of the size of the data, Census requires that you specify a "regionin" (i.e., state or county) for the data import.  So I need to run through a list of all the states (by fips code) in order to get all of the data imported.  The output I need are separate dataframes for each state that I can then work with and combine into one large dataframe.  Here is an example of the code I have written:

```
library(censusapi)

states <- c("01","02")
for(i in 1:length(states)) {
   region = str_glue("state:{states[i]}")
   migr = str_glue("migr2010_{states[i]}")
   migr <- getCensus(name = "acs/flows", vintage = 2010,
                     key = "*myAPIkey*",
                     vars = c("MOVEDNET", "MOVEDIN", "MOVEDOUT", "AGE"),
                     region = "county:*", regionin = region)
}
```

What I want to get out are separate dataframes for each state named "migr2010_01", "migr2010_02", etc.  What I am actually getting out is one dataframe named "migr" with only the data from the last state on the list.  I know there is something wrong in my loop, but I am not sure where I need to make the change as I am new to R loops.
Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code creates an object called `migr`, and assigns it a string with the name of the data.frame you want to create.  Then you overwrite the the `migr` object with the data.frame that you pull from Census.  Each iteration of the loop, you overwrite `migr`, which is why only the data from the last iteration of the loop is saved, and then only as a data.frame named `migr`.

Instead, you need to use the `assign` command to assign the data you pull from Census to the value stored in `migr`, as follows:

```
library(censusapi)

states <- c("01","02")
for(i in 1:length(states)) {
   region = str_glue("state:{states[i]}")
   migr = str_glue("migr2010_{states[i]}")
   assign(
     x = migr,
     value = getCensus(name = "acs/flows", vintage = 2010,
                       key = "*myAPIkey*",
                       vars = c("MOVEDNET", "MOVEDIN", "MOVEDOUT", "AGE"),
                       region = "county:*", regionin = region)
   )
}
```

## Edit

As others have mentioned, it may be easier to work with a list of data.frames, rather than creating several in the global environment. The easiest way to create that is using `lapply`, as follows:

```
 migr2010 <- lapply(
   paste0("state:", c("01", "02")),  # replaces region in the original
   getCensus,
   name = "acs/flows",
   vintage = 2010,
   key = "*myAPIkey*",
   vars = c("MOVEDNET", "MOVEDIN", "MOVEDOUT", "AGE"),
   region = "county:*"
   )
```

Then, if you want to create a single data.frame out of those, you could use `dplyr::bind_rows(migr2010)`, `data.table::rbindlist(migr2010)`, or `do.call(rbind, migr2010)` (although `do.call` is much slower than the other two).

Comment: THANK YOU!  Can I ask why I have to assign the value for migr but I don't need to for region?  Or is the "regionin = region" doing the same thing?

Comment: R does the same thing to `region` -- it overwrites it at each iteration of the loop.  But, you only need `region` to call `getCensus`, so you don't need to save the value of `region` for later.  (By the way, if I answered your question, please mark it as answered. :))

Comment: I highly recommend R for Data Science for a better explanation: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html .

Comment: This answers the question but it's a bad idea and it's bad practice, should come at least with a warning, other solutions are much cleaner.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I edited it to add the list solution.  I didn't put it in the original because that's not what he asked.

Answer (score 2):

Simply turn your process into a function and pass into `lapply` or better yet `sapply` for named list (since it inputs a character vector). Reconsider saving similarly structured, and potentially many objects separately but use **one** named list of data frames. Avoid flooding global environment unnecessarily:

```
library(stringr)
library(censusapi)

states <- c("01","02")

get_census_data <- function(st)
   region = str_glue("state:{st}")
   migr = str_glue("migr2010_{st}")

   migr <- getCensus(name = "acs/flows", vintage = 2010,
                     key = "*myAPIkey*",
                     vars = c("MOVEDNET", "MOVEDIN", "MOVEDOUT", "AGE"),
                     region = "county:*", regionin = region)
}

df_list <- sapply(states, get_census_data, simplify=FALSE)
# df_list <- setNames(lapply(states, get_census_data), states)   # EQUIVALENT CALL
```

You lose no functionality of data frame if it is stored in a list as opposed to a separate object:

```
str(df_list$`01`)
head(df_list$`01`)
summary(df_list$`01`)

dim(df_list$`02`)
tail(df_list$`02`)
table(df_list$`02`)
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using `sapply` with `simplify=FALSE` instead of just using `lapply`?

Comment: `sapply` has `USE.NAMES = TRUE` by default, `lapply` behaves like  `USE.NAMES = FALSE`

Comment: @GregSnow ... I explain `sapply` renders a named list since it takes a character vector as input.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in part by [FAQ 7.21](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f).  The most important part of that answer is the end where it says that it is easier to just use a list.

Your code can be converted to something like:

```
library(censusapi)
library(stringr)

states <- c("01","02")
migr.list <- lapply( states, function(x) {
   region = str_glue("state:{x}")
   migr = str_glue("migr2010_{x}")
   getCensus(name = "acs/flows", vintage = 2010,
                     key = "*myAPIkey*",
                     vars = c("MOVEDNET", "MOVEDIN", "MOVEDOUT", "AGE"),
                     region = "county:*", regionin = region)
})
names(migr.list) <- sprintf("migr2010_%s", states) # optional
```

Now `migr.list` will be a single list object with each element being the data frame returned by `getCensus`.  If you want to combine these all together into 1 data frame you can use code like:

```
migr <- do.call(rbind, migr.list)
```

If you want to run the same code on each state separately then you can just use `lapply` or related functions.  In the long run this will be much simpler and less error prone than using `get` and `assign` with loops.